# Launch a new terminator window with a keyboard shortcut without starting a new process

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminator

I have been a long-time `xfce4-terminal` user. However, I have recently enjoyed a few of the benefits of using `terminator` as my main terminal emulator. I have a keyboard shortcut to launch new terminal windows, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> for launching the command `terminator -m`. However, every time I hit the keyboard shortcut a new `terminator` process starts. With `xfce4-terminal` I can hit this same keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> for `xfce4-terminal --maximize`) multiple times to open multiple terminal windows, and it only uses one process. Is there a way to achieve this same functionality in Terminator. (I know I can click on an open terminal and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to launch a new window under the same pid, but I would like to achieve this functionality via a keyboard shortcut that I can launch no matter what program is in the foreground. If it is of any benefit, I am running Xfce on Debian 9. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `--new-tab` switch to the configured keyboard shortcut :

```
terminator --new-tab
```

Comment: I had tried this one. I have the `DBus server` option unchecked in Preferences because of a bug in Xfce. So, this flag does actually open a new window, but each new window has its own process as before. Thanks though.

Comment: I think this is the only one solution if you want to use `terminator`. Can't you upgrade your OS ? Maybe the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks! This is great for me that always end up with 300 terminals open :)